# JSP variables across pages

Tags: jsp

I have a jsp page which contains ten variables which I have to forward it to another page when user clicks a button. One way to achieve this is to append those to the url and send it, but I am not sure whether the number of variables may increase. Is there anyway that I can transfer these variables?

Comment: Could you provide a code example of what you mean by "JSP variables?"  How are they created and how do they need to be accessed?

Comment: i can paste the code here...but there is a lot of css stuff added to that which makes it hard to read it. what would u do if u have some 100 variables retrieved from database to forward them to a different page. any datastructure?

Comment: Btw i would suggest also to take the CSS to an external .css file. :)

Comment: I don't need to see everything, just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these values come from form input elements, put them in a form and use a proper submit button.

If these are simply variables for application logic, put them into the session or some other context that persists across requests.